# How to derive from a pimpl class?

Tags: c++

Let's say the scenario is this.

1. `IBase` - interface.
2. `BaseImpl` - implementation.
3. `BaseStub` - allocates `std::unique_ptr` to `BaseImpl` named `m_impl`.

And then how to achieve the following?

1. `IDerived` - interface.
2. `DerivedImpl` - implementation, inherits from `BaseImpl`.
3. `DerivedStub` - allocates `std::unique_ptr` to `DerivedImpl` named `m_impl`, inherits from `BaseStub`.

It becomes a problem that BaseStub already allocates its implementation, and since `DerivedStub` does the same, it conflicts.

```
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual void f1() = 0;
};

class IDerived
{
public:
    virtual void f2() = 0;
};

class BaseImpl : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual void f1() override {}
};

class DerivedImpl : public BaseImpl, public IDerived
{
public:
    virtual void f2() override {}
};

class BaseStub : public IBase
{
public:
    BaseStub() { m_impl.reset(new BaseImpl()); }

    virtual void f1() override { m_impl->f1(); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<BaseImpl> m_impl;
};

// But this also creates BaseStub::m_impl.
class DerivedStub : public BaseStub, public IDerived
{
public:
    DerivedStub() { m_impl.reset(new DerivedImpl()); }

    virtual void f2() override { m_impl->f2(); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedImpl> m_impl;
};
```

Comment: can you provide a code example to show what you'd like to achieve and what is the problem?

Comment: @lizusek, I edited the question a bit. Anyway, short story: BaseStub has a member m_impl. DerivedStub inhertis from BaseStub and would also like to have a member m_impl. But BaseStub already has it. Conflict.

Comment: BaseStub is a class? How is this related to BaseImpl and IBase? I think you are mixing up the things

Comment: @lizusek, yes, so is BaseImpl.

Comment: How about introducing `m_impl_derived`? Seems like a bad idea in general though. Please make your example more concrete.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the problem that you are facing at an higher level? There might be better solution to this problem, and I'm personally inclined to think so.

Comment: Alright, I've edited the question again to express what I want to do. Basically I have stub classes and implementation classes, stub classes will just forward everything to the m_impl data members. But I want the stub classes to follow the same inheritance hierarchy as the implementation classes.

Comment: I agree with @Jefffrey. There is probably a better solution that what are doing for your problem.